# Ionic 2 (uses Angular 2) - how to access functions of another page?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am quite new to Ionic and Angular 2:

I was trying to make a service (or provider in Ionic 2), which will hold my global variables and global functions.

When I tried importing AlertController and LoadingController (instantiate it via on my service file's constructor and call it's methods on one of my service file's functions) in my service file, I would get an error saying "No Provider for AlertController" etc.

So, I thought - I could make a page called "CommonFunctions", which I can use as a wrapper around my service/provider functions - This way I can separate the Data Functions and the UI functions (AlertContorller etc.).
[See this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26aMU.png)

I'm now getting an error saying "No Provider for CommonFunctions". I declared CommonFunctions as a normal page, but I'm guessing I can't use CommonFunctions functions on another page?

So my current choices (that I can think of is):

1. How can I call AlertController/LoadingController (or Controllers alike)
   in a service/provider
2. How can I use another page's functions
3. If these are not possible, I guess I'll have to just accept that I
   can't call AlertController/LoadingController function on a service
   (this would mean a lot of repetition of code too).

Any help is very much appreciated.

exercise.ts is the main page seen by user

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FirebaseListObservable , FirebaseObjectObservable} from 'angularfire2';
import { Common } from '../common/common'; 

@Component({
  selector: 'page-exercise',
  templateUrl: 'exercise.html'
})
export class ExercisePage {

  public FBexercises: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

  constructor(
      public navCtrl: NavController,
      public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
      public common: Common
    ) {
    this.getFBexercises();
  }

  getFBexercises(){
    let that = this;

      this.common.getFBLUL().then(function(){
      that.exerciseLUL = this.glob_var.exerciseLUL;
      that.exerciseLUL_backup = this.glob_var.exerciseLUL_backup;
      that.muscleGroupLUL = this.glob_var.muscleGroupLUL;
      that.muscleLUL = this.glob_var.muscleLUL;
    });
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('Exercise Page Loaded');
  }


}
```

common.ts is a page, but I intend to use it to store my global functions

```
import {Component, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {GlobalVars} from '../../providers/global-vars';
import {NavController, AlertController, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-common',
  templateUrl: 'common.html'
})

@Injectable()
export class Common {

    public static navCtrl: NavController
    public static alertCtrl: AlertController
    public static loadingCtrl : LoadingController
    public static globalVars: GlobalVars

    constructor () {
    }
     //creates loading bar
    createLoadingBar(message){
        return this.loadingCtrl.create({
          content: message
        });
    }

    getFBLUL(){
        let that = this;
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
              //create loading bar
            var loadingBar = that.createLoadingBar('Exercise List loading');
            loadingBar.present();
            that.globalVars.FBexercisesToLUL().then(function(){
                loadingBar.dismiss();

          //TO-DO, receive exerciseLUL from FBexerciseToLUL() and return it when promise finishes

                resolve();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

global-vars.ts is my data service i use to grab my data from firebase database

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

@Injectable()
export class GlobalVars {

  public muscleGroupLUL = [];
  public muscleLUL = [];
  public exerciseLUL = [];
  public exerciseLUL_backup = [];

  public FB_exercise: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

  constructor(
    public af: AngularFire
    ) {
    this.getFBexercise();
  }

  getFBexercise() {
    console.log("Getting FB Exercises");
    this.FB_exercise = this.af.database.list('/Exercise');
  }

  FBexercisesToLUL() {
    let that = this;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        that.muscleGroupLUL.push("");
        that.muscleLUL.push("");

        that.FB_exercise.subscribe(exercises => {
          console.log("Exercises Loaded");
            // items is an array

            exercises.forEach(FBexercise => {

            var ref = FBexercise.$key;
              var muscleGroup = FBexercise.body_part_name;
              var muscle = FBexercise.muscle_name;
              var exercise = FBexercise.exercise_name;

            if (that.muscleGroupLUL.indexOf(muscleGroup) === -1) { //if not in LUL
                that.muscleGroupLUL.push(muscleGroup);
            }
                if (that.muscleLUL.indexOf(muscle) === -1) { //if not in LUL
                that.muscleLUL.push(muscle);
            }
            if (that.exerciseLUL.indexOf(exercise) === -1) { //if not in LUL
                that.exerciseLUL.push({ref:ref, exercise: exercise, muscle : muscle, muscleGroup : muscleGroup});
            }

          });

          that.exerciseLUL_backup = that.exerciseLUL;

      //TO-DO, return exerciseLUL when promise finishes 

          resolve();

      });
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you have to declare providers before you can use them.

There is an example of provider declaration:

```
@NgModule({
   ...
   providers: [
       MyService
   ]
})
```

Your service class should be decorated with `@Injectable()`.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
   ...
}
```

Then you can inject this service into any component's constructor.

```
@Component({
    ...
})
export class MyComponent {
    constructor(serviceVariable: MyService) {
        serviceVariable.someMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Mateusz,
I am trying to create a page which contains my UI functions (like loading an alert modal). I have created a service for getting data. What I intend to do is call the page functions ---which then calls the--->service

The issue is that I cannot import/inject my Page Class (with my UI functions) onto another page. I keep getting an error telling me that my Page Class should be a provider, however if I declare it as a provider I will get an error, telling me that I cannot use AlertController on my Page Class because I have no provider for AlertController)

Comment: Can you upload some code? It would be easier for me to understand what you are trying to do.